# JPA - Map child entity class to parent when parent has two child objects

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I have a Shipment Entity class where there are two ShipmentAddress, one for the delivery address and the other, the destination address:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "shipment")
public class Shipment {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne
    private AppUser user;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private ShipmentAddress fromAddress;

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private ShipmentAddress toAddress;
}
```

I have a ShipmentAddress Entity class where it looks like this:

```
@Entity
public class ShipmentAddress {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String street1;
    private String street2;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "fromAddress")
    private Shipment shipment;

    @OneToOne(mappedBy = "toAddress")
    private Shipment shipment;
}
```

I think we can agree that it is redunant to have two properties to define a Shipment inside ShipmentAddress, because they both point to the same Shipment. In ShipmentAddress class, I want to be able to have one Shipment in the ShipmentAddress Entity. JPA does not support multiple @OneToOne annotations for the same entity class. How can I accomplish this?